# Can I use apache virtual hosts to have many prefixes?

Tags: apache

I'm just learning about Apache virtual hosts.  I'd like to have two virtual hosts of the form:

- `sitea.mydomain.org`
- `siteb.mydomain.org`

I own mydomain.org and both `sitea.mydomain.org` and `siteb.mydomain.org` of the NS points to the same IP address.  I thought I could get the server to point to different webpages by making two sites in `sites-available` called `sitea.mydomain.org` and `siteb.mydomain.org`, but both of those entries seem to resolve to the `default` site.

Does this sound like a correct configuration, or even something that's possible?  If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having those two files, you will need to have ServerName and maybe ServerAlias-Directives in them. For example in the file sitea.mydomain.org:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitea.mydomain.org
    ServerAlias www.sitea.mydomain.org anothersitea.mydomain.org
    DocumentRoot /root/directory
</VirtualHost>
```

Same goes for siteb. Also, create a symlink into sites-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `a2ensite` after creating a site in `sites-available`.

It does a necessary job, and put a symbolic link in `sites-enabled`.

Comment: These are debian proprietary utilities/paths.

Comment: @covener: Interesting remark. In fact, I use apache mostly on Debian and Ubuntu. And each time I used it on another platform without a2ensite, there was neither `sites-available` nor `sites-enabled`. Is there a case where those directories are used and a2ensite is not available?